# Hadoop hdfs namenode start command fails. Not formatted either?

Tags: hadoop, centos, centos6, cloudera-cdh

Much like states when I run the command `sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start` the command failed with the below message.

```
2015-02-01 16:51:22,032 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2015-02-01 16:51:22,379 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-namenode.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
2015-02-01 16:51:22,512 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2015-02-01 16:51:22,512 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2015-02-01 16:51:23,043 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Only one image storage directory (dfs.namenode.name.dir) configured. Beware of dataloss due to lack of redundant storage directories!
2015-02-01 16:51:23,043 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Only one namespace edits storage directory (dfs.namenode.edits.dir) configured. Beware of dataloss due to lack of redundant storage directories!
2015-02-01 16:51:23,096 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair:true
2015-02-01 16:51:23,214 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.HeartbeatManager: Setting heartbeat recheck interval to 30000 since dfs.namenode.stale.datanode.interval is less than dfs.namenode.heartbeat.recheck-interval
2015-02-01 16:51:23,223 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
2015-02-01 16:51:23,227 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
2015-02-01 16:51:23,227 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2015-02-01 16:51:23,232 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 889 MB = 17.8 MB
2015-02-01 16:51:23,233 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
2015-02-01 16:51:23,242 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
2015-02-01 16:51:23,242 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 1
2015-02-01 16:51:23,242 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
2015-02-01 16:51:23,242 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
2015-02-01 16:51:23,242 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
2015-02-01 16:51:23,242 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: shouldCheckForEnoughRacks  = false
2015-02-01 16:51:23,243 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
2015-02-01 16:51:23,243 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
2015-02-01 16:51:23,243 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
2015-02-01 16:51:23,253 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = hdfs (auth:SIMPLE)
2015-02-01 16:51:23,254 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
2015-02-01 16:51:23,254 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = false
2015-02-01 16:51:23,254 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
2015-02-01 16:51:23,259 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
2015-02-01 16:51:23,555 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
2015-02-01 16:51:23,558 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
2015-02-01 16:51:23,558 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
2015-02-01 16:51:23,558 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 0
2015-02-01 16:51:23,563 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/name does not exist
2015-02-01 16:51:23,565 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NameNode metrics system...
2015-02-01 16:51:23,565 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.
2015-02-01 16:51:23,565 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
2015-02-01 16:51:23,566 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:741)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1241)
2015-02-01 16:51:23,571 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2015-02-01 16:51:23,573 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at hadoop/127.0.0.1
************************************************************/
```

The error itself is pretty self explanatory, the directory /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/name is missing which is correct. The cache directory was empty so I created /cache/hdfs/dfs/name. I also changed the owner and group to match that of the directory above them. hdfs:hadoop.

I again run the format command `sudo -u hdfs hdfs namenode –format` which ends the same way as it did prior to creating this directory.

```
STARTUP_MSG:   build = file:///data/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-rhel64-6-0/topdir/BUILD/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.7.1/src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common -r Unknown; compiled by 'jenkins' on Tue Nov 18 08:10:25 PST 2014
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_75
************************************************************/
15/02/01 17:09:04 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
Usage: java NameNode [-backup] | [-checkpoint] | [-format [-clusterid cid ] [-force] [-nonInteractive] ] | [-upgrade] | [-rollback] | [-finalize] | [-importCheckpoint] | [-initializeSharedEdits] | [-bootstrapStandby] | [-recover [ -force ] ]

15/02/01 17:09:04 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at hadoop/127.0.0.1
```

Now I run the namenode start command again and receive the following error:

```
STARTUP_MSG:   build = file:///data/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-rhel64-6-0/topdir/BUILD/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.7.1/src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common -r Unknown; compiled by 'jenkins' on Tue Nov 18 08:10:25 PST 2014
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_75
************************************************************/
2015-02-01 17:09:26,774 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2015-02-01 17:09:27,097 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-namenode.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
2015-02-01 17:09:27,215 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2015-02-01 17:09:27,216 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2015-02-01 17:09:27,721 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Only one image storage directory (dfs.namenode.name.dir) configured. Beware of dataloss due to lack of redundant storage directories!
2015-02-01 17:09:27,721 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Only one namespace edits storage directory (dfs.namenode.edits.dir) configured. Beware of dataloss due to lack of redundant storage directories!
2015-02-01 17:09:27,779 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair:true
2015-02-01 17:09:27,883 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.HeartbeatManager: Setting heartbeat recheck interval to 30000 since dfs.namenode.stale.datanode.interval is less than dfs.namenode.heartbeat.recheck-interval
2015-02-01 17:09:27,890 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
2015-02-01 17:09:27,895 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
2015-02-01 17:09:27,895 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2015-02-01 17:09:27,899 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 889 MB = 17.8 MB
2015-02-01 17:09:27,899 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
2015-02-01 17:09:27,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
2015-02-01 17:09:27,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 1
2015-02-01 17:09:27,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
2015-02-01 17:09:27,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
2015-02-01 17:09:27,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
2015-02-01 17:09:27,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: shouldCheckForEnoughRacks  = false
2015-02-01 17:09:27,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
2015-02-01 17:09:27,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
2015-02-01 17:09:27,910 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
2015-02-01 17:09:27,918 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = hdfs (auth:SIMPLE)
2015-02-01 17:09:27,918 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
2015-02-01 17:09:27,918 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = false
2015-02-01 17:09:27,918 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
2015-02-01 17:09:27,924 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
2015-02-01 17:09:28,178 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
2015-02-01 17:09:28,180 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
2015-02-01 17:09:28,180 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
2015-02-01 17:09:28,180 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 0
2015-02-01 17:09:28,193 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Lock on /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/name/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 28482@hadoop
2015-02-01 17:09:28,196 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NameNode metrics system...
2015-02-01 17:09:28,196 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.
2015-02-01 17:09:28,196 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
2015-02-01 17:09:28,197 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:741)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1241)
2015-02-01 17:09:28,202 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2015-02-01 17:09:28,205 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at hadoop/127.0.0.1
************************************************************/
```

My system is running in VirtualBox with a CentOS 6.6 guest, Oracle JDK 1.7, and attempting to run Cloudera CDH4. Any input on what to do next to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy and paste the format command from slides or something, can you actually type it and see if it works?

I don't know if you can see the different between

–format and -format.

The dash looks different to me.

Comment: I can try that tonight. It should be noted that running the deprecated "hadoop namenode format" command actually does do a format. Forgive my syntax there...off the top of my head at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue formatting the namenode. Retyped the commando (not copy-paste):

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

it worked. Thx https://stackoverflow.com/users/4533812/james